# Error Installing Service with InstallUtil

Tags: command-line, services, windows-services

I've recently created a Windows Service and am attempting to install it using InstallUtil.

The service I am trying to install works/installs correctly on a machine running Windows 2008, but I am having trouble getting that same service to install on a Windows 2003 Box.

After running InstallUtil.exe WindowsService.exe in a Command Prompt (Running as an Admin) I get this Error:

> An exception occurred during the install phase.
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>   The RollBack phase of the installation is beginning... etc.
>   ... 
>   The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.

*What could be causing the error in my install*, considering this exact Windows Service installs correctly on the Windows 2008 box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Win32Exception: Access is denied

Windows does not allow you to do something because of security restrictions. Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out what exactly.